# How to set caret to newly added element in contentEditable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am working on a WYSIWYG editor in which I want to add `<p>`'s when hit Enter / Return key and then the user will write to this new `<p>`.

Right now I am having issue setting the caret to this new `<p>`.

```js
$('#content').on('keypress', function(e){
    
    if(e.which === 13){
        
        console.log('enter pressed');
        
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

        var element = document.createElement('p');

        // element.textContent = 'lorem';  // gets added in the right position
        
        range.insertNode(element);
        
        // range.setStart(element);   // doesn't work
        
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='content' contentEditable=true>test</p>
```

I need to get this working in Chrome for now.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution if you don't absolutely need the top `contenteditable` element to be a `p` element, is to add a `contenteditable` div as parent of your `p` element. Enter will automatically add `p` elements.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content' contentEditable=true><p>test</p></div>
```